# Phonegap Javascript, No pide permisos el micrófono

Tags: javascript, ios, phonegap

Tengo una app en phonegap que usa un socket por el que manda los datos del microfono, le problema que tengo es que en ios (en andriod si funciona) no pide los permisos para usar el microfono por lo tanto no manda datos.

```
inicio del microfono:

     function initAudio() {

var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;
permissions.hasPermission(permissions.RECORD_AUDIO, function( status ){
    if ( status.hasPermission ) {

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({'audio': true}).then(function(mediaStream) {
            gotStream(mediaStream);
        });

    }
    else {
      console.log("no");
    }
    });}

config.xml

    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" />

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.4.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="~1.4.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" source="npm"/>

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" />
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-media-recorder" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.1.0" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" launch-external="yes" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" launch-external="yes" />
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="overwrite" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
    <string>We are using the Camera for scan qr codes</string>
</edit-config>
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="overwrite" target="NSMicrophoneUsageDescription">
    <string>We are using the mic for a streaming to a server of audio recognition</string>
</edit-config>
```